# Clearing chromium cookies from a site when loading it?

Tags: chrome

Is it possible to set the Chromium such that when I visit a particular site, it clears those cookies got from this site but not from the other sites and allows the cookies the particular site offers?

Comment: Yes, it's called private browsing mode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

Comment: pbm does not clear the cookies.

Comment: @bahamat Uh??? Chromium is a Unix application, so the question is on-topic. The fact that it also runs on other platforms is irrelevant.